# How to remove undesired objects from image using scipy?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to remove undesired pixels that are false positives from my image after segmented it by labeling the pixels and removing small objects.
However, it still returning some false positives.

I'm trying to implement the below algorithm described in the [paper](http://www.scielo.edu.uy/pdf/cleiej/v19n1/v19n1a07.pdf):

```
n, components ← connectedComponents(segmentedImage)
components ← deleteSmallComponents(components, kMinimumArea)
if size(components) == 1 then
   return components[0]
end if
inters ← empty
areas ← empty
for all component in components do
    inters ← inters ∪ getImageMarginIntersections(component)
    areas ← areas ∪ getComponentArea(component)
end for
noisyObject ← max(inters)
return max(areas − noisyObject)
```

So far, I have implemented part of it as follow:

```
def undesired_objects ( image ):
    components, n = ndimage.label( image )
    components = skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects( components, min_size = 150 )
    plot.imshow( components )
    plot.show()
```

I'm unable to insert an image, imgur is always returning error. Thus, if you wish to take a look to an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7vOl.jpg).

The first Leaf is the original image, the second is the segmented image, the third is the labeled image, and the last one is the end result which still have some false positives [Yellow Pixels].

Comment: Are the false positives pixels unconnected small objects, or are they connected to your larger object and you just happen to not perfectly line up the leaf border with your ground-truth? If it is the latter it suggests it might be a threshold issue, but getting the exact threshold will be very difficult. You could try morphological transforms (erosion then dilation) to try and make a cleaner border, but this might not be something which you can reliably get to be exact.

Comment: @Mozglubov I think that the false positives are connected to the larger object, because if I check a second time using ndimage.label, it returns the value 1